# BufferedOutputStream multiple lines Write in File

Tags: java, bufferedwriter, gzipoutputstream, bufferedoutputstream

I have a little problem with a function I made. 
I want that everytime I give a string to this function, it will save me to a new Line in the same file, but actually now is saving only the last string Im givving. It's like overwriting again and again, Need some help

```
public void WritingGZFile(String directory, String linesWithPattern, String newFile) throws IOException
    {
        newFile = directory + '\\' + newFile;
            BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                    newFile)));
            out.write(linesWithPattern.getBytes());
            out.write("\r\n".getBytes());
            out.close();
    }
```

For example in BufferedWriter Has a method called newLine that helps to do that.

But since I want to use GZIPOutputStream class I need BufferedOutputStream.

Any ideeas how to do it? Thank ypu

Comment: What happens if you do new FileOutputStream(newFile, true) to tell it to append rather than rewrite?

Comment: When using BufferedOutputStream, you should also use `out.flush()` before you close it.

Comment: @Ascalonian There is no need to `flush()` if you `close()`.

Comment: @ControlAltDel That was the right solution.

Comment: BTW: using string.getBytes() is dangerous as it does not define what encoding to use. You better specify one (usually UTF-8) or use a Writer which can take a string directly (and specify the encoding in the writer).

Comment: @Ascalonian as I understand flush() writes the content of the buffer to the destination and makes the buffer empty for further data to store but it does not closes the stream permanently. That means you can still write some more data to the stream.

But close() closes the stream permanently. If you want to write some data further, then you have to reopen the stream again and append the data with the existing ones.

Comment: @eckes will something like this be ok? 

    `out.write(linesWithPattern.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));`

Comment: yes or you can use `final static Charset UTF8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8")` or StandardCharsets.UTF_8 in Java 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are exactly right, you overwrite the file. If you open it with an `FileOutputStream` it will start from the beginning. You can either keep the stream open or use the [append mode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29) by specifying `true` after the file (name).

```
BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(
                                 new GZIPOutputStream(
                                       new FileOutputStream(newFile, true)
                                     )
                                );
```

With the GZIPOutputStream you have quite some overhead if you open a new stream on each line, but it is defined to work this way. (Again: keeping it open also helps with this).

Comment: Thank you man, that worked :D:D. I forgot about this mode. Thank you again!